# How to take the comments which are not related to the functioning and variables with Doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

My Doxygen version : Doxyfile 1.8.20

Doxygen takes the comments of functions, variables...
But if for example I want to comment on an if, it is not taken into account in the doc.
I would like to have a comment section per piece of code that I comment on.

I want to be able to retrieve the comments not related to the function and variables

```
   /**
    * Description : if comment
    */
   if ($tri != 0) {
      if ($tri == -1)
         $tri = 0;
      $_SESSION["stat"]["tri"] = $tri;
   }
   elseif (isset($_SESSION["stat"]["tri"])) {
      $tri = $_SESSION["stat"]["tri"];
   }
   $smarty->assign("tri", $tri);
```

I have test the command @internal, but it not works ...

I can't find the exact case I'm looking for in the documentation.
However, I just want to display the comments that interest me in addition to the functions and variables. I am sure it is possible. Maybe something to change in my configuration.

Here is my configuration, if anyone has an idea?

My configuration :

```
# Doxyfile 1.8.20

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Project related configuration options
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DOXYFILE_ENCODING      = UTF-8
PROJECT_NAME           = projectName
PROJECT_NUMBER         =
PROJECT_BRIEF          = ""
PROJECT_LOGO           = ./images/logo.png
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY       = ../testdoc
CREATE_SUBDIRS         = NO
ALLOW_UNICODE_NAMES    = NO
OUTPUT_LANGUAGE        = French
OUTPUT_TEXT_DIRECTION  = None
BRIEF_MEMBER_DESC      = YES
REPEAT_BRIEF           = YES
ABBREVIATE_BRIEF       = "The $name class" \
                         "The $name widget" \
                         "The $name file" \
                         is \
                         provides \
                         specifies \
                         contains \
                         represents \
                         a \
                         an \
                         the
ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC    = NO
INLINE_INHERITED_MEMB  = NO
FULL_PATH_NAMES        = YES
STRIP_FROM_PATH        =
STRIP_FROM_INC_PATH    =
SHORT_NAMES            = NO
JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF      = YES
JAVADOC_BANNER         = NO
QT_AUTOBRIEF           = NO
MULTILINE_CPP_IS_BRIEF = NO
PYTHON_DOCSTRING       = YES
INHERIT_DOCS           = YES
SEPARATE_MEMBER_PAGES  = NO
TAB_SIZE               = 4
ALIASES                =
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_FOR_C  = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_JAVA   = YES
OPTIMIZE_FOR_FORTRAN   = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_VHDL   = NO
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_SLICE  = NO
EXTENSION_MAPPING      =
MARKDOWN_SUPPORT       = YES
TOC_INCLUDE_HEADINGS   = 5
AUTOLINK_SUPPORT       = YES
BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT    = NO
CPP_CLI_SUPPORT        = NO
SIP_SUPPORT            = NO
IDL_PROPERTY_SUPPORT   = YES
DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC   = NO
GROUP_NESTED_COMPOUNDS = NO
SUBGROUPING            = YES
INLINE_GROUPED_CLASSES = NO
INLINE_SIMPLE_STRUCTS  = NO
TYPEDEF_HIDES_STRUCT   = NO
LOOKUP_CACHE_SIZE      = 0
NUM_PROC_THREADS       = 1
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Build related configuration options
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = NO
EXTRACT_PRIV_VIRTUAL   = NO
EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = NO
EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_CLASSES  = YES
EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = YES
EXTRACT_ANON_NSPACES   = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS     = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES     = NO
HIDE_FRIEND_COMPOUNDS  = NO
HIDE_IN_BODY_DOCS      = NO
INTERNAL_DOCS          = YES
CASE_SENSE_NAMES       = NO
HIDE_SCOPE_NAMES       = YES
HIDE_COMPOUND_REFERENCE= NO
SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES     = YES
SHOW_GROUPED_MEMB_INC  = NO
FORCE_LOCAL_INCLUDES   = NO
INLINE_INFO            = YES
SORT_MEMBER_DOCS       = YES
SORT_BRIEF_DOCS        = NO
SORT_MEMBERS_CTORS_1ST = YES
SORT_GROUP_NAMES       = YES
SORT_BY_SCOPE_NAME     = YES
STRICT_PROTO_MATCHING  = NO
GENERATE_TODOLIST      = YES
GENERATE_TESTLIST      = YES
GENERATE_BUGLIST       = YES
GENERATE_DEPRECATEDLIST= YES
ENABLED_SECTIONS       = INTERNAL
MAX_INITIALIZER_LINES  = 30
SHOW_USED_FILES        = YES
SHOW_FILES             = YES
SHOW_NAMESPACES        = YES
FILE_VERSION_FILTER    =
LAYOUT_FILE            =
CITE_BIB_FILES         =
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to warning and progress messages
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
QUIET                  = NO
WARNINGS               = YES
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = YES
WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR      = YES
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC       = NO
WARN_AS_ERROR          = NO
WARN_FORMAT            = "$file:$line: $text"
WARN_LOGFILE           =
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the input files
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
INPUT                  = .
INPUT_ENCODING         = UTF-8
FILE_PATTERNS          = *.c \
                         *.cc \
                         *.cxx \
                         *.cpp \
                         *.c++ \
                         *.java \
                         *.ii \
                         *.ixx \
                         *.ipp \
                         *.i++ \
                         *.inl \
                         *.idl \
                         *.ddl \
                         *.odl \
                         *.h \
                         *.hh \
                         *.hxx \
                         *.hpp \
                         *.h++ \
                         *.cs \
                         *.d \
                         *.php \
                         *.php4 \
                         *.php5 \
                         *.phtml \
                         *.inc \
                         *.m \
                         *.markdown \
                         *.md \
                         *.mm \
                         *.dox \
                         *.py \
                         *.pyw \
                         *.f90 \
                         *.f95 \
                         *.f03 \
                         *.f08 \
                         *.f \
                         *.for \
                         *.tcl \
                         *.vhd \
                         *.vhdl \
                         *.ucf \
                         *.qsf \
                         *.ice
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXCLUDE                = ./cache \
                         ./templates_c \
                         ./lib \
                         ./log \
                         ./tests \
                         "./en production" \
                         ./sysop/templates_c
EXCLUDE_SYMLINKS       = NO
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       =
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        =
EXAMPLE_PATH           =
EXAMPLE_PATTERNS       = *
EXAMPLE_RECURSIVE      = NO
IMAGE_PATH             =
INPUT_FILTER           =
FILTER_PATTERNS        =
FILTER_SOURCE_FILES    = NO
FILTER_SOURCE_PATTERNS =
USE_MDFILE_AS_MAINPAGE =
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to source browsing
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
SOURCE_BROWSER         = NO
INLINE_SOURCES         = NO
STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS    = NO
REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = NO
REFERENCES_RELATION    = NO
REFERENCES_LINK_SOURCE = YES
SOURCE_TOOLTIPS        = YES
USE_HTAGS              = NO
VERBATIM_HEADERS       = YES
CLANG_ASSISTED_PARSING = NO
CLANG_OPTIONS          =
CLANG_DATABASE_PATH    =
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the alphabetical class index
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALPHABETICAL_INDEX     = YES
COLS_IN_ALPHA_INDEX    = 5
IGNORE_PREFIX          =
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the HTML output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_HTML          = YES
HTML_OUTPUT            = .
HTML_FILE_EXTENSION    = .html
HTML_HEADER            =
HTML_FOOTER            =
HTML_STYLESHEET        =
HTML_EXTRA_STYLESHEET  =
HTML_EXTRA_FILES       =
HTML_COLORSTYLE_HUE    = 220
HTML_COLORSTYLE_SAT    = 100
HTML_COLORSTYLE_GAMMA  = 80
HTML_TIMESTAMP         = YES
HTML_DYNAMIC_MENUS     = YES
HTML_DYNAMIC_SECTIONS  = YES
HTML_INDEX_NUM_ENTRIES = 100
GENERATE_DOCSET        = NO
DOCSET_FEEDNAME        = "Doxygen generated docs"
DOCSET_BUNDLE_ID       = org.doxygen.Project
DOCSET_PUBLISHER_ID    = org.doxygen.Publisher
DOCSET_PUBLISHER_NAME  = Publisher
GENERATE_HTMLHELP      = NO
CHM_FILE               =
HHC_LOCATION           =
GENERATE_CHI           = NO
CHM_INDEX_ENCODING     =
BINARY_TOC             = NO
TOC_EXPAND             = NO
GENERATE_QHP           = NO
QCH_FILE               =
QHP_NAMESPACE          = org.doxygen.Project
QHP_VIRTUAL_FOLDER     = doc
QHP_CUST_FILTER_NAME   =
QHP_CUST_FILTER_ATTRS  =
QHP_SECT_FILTER_ATTRS  =
QHG_LOCATION           =
GENERATE_ECLIPSEHELP   = NO
ECLIPSE_DOC_ID         = org.doxygen.Project
DISABLE_INDEX          = NO
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = NO
ENUM_VALUES_PER_LINE   = 4
TREEVIEW_WIDTH         = 250
EXT_LINKS_IN_WINDOW    = NO
HTML_FORMULA_FORMAT    = png
FORMULA_FONTSIZE       = 10
FORMULA_TRANSPARENT    = YES
FORMULA_MACROFILE      =
USE_MATHJAX            = NO
MATHJAX_FORMAT         = HTML-CSS
MATHJAX_RELPATH        = https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/
MATHJAX_EXTENSIONS     =
MATHJAX_CODEFILE       =
SEARCHENGINE           = YES
SERVER_BASED_SEARCH    = NO
EXTERNAL_SEARCH        = NO
SEARCHENGINE_URL       =
SEARCHDATA_FILE        = searchdata.xml
EXTERNAL_SEARCH_ID     =
EXTRA_SEARCH_MAPPINGS  =
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the LaTeX output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
LATEX_OUTPUT           = latex
LATEX_CMD_NAME         =
MAKEINDEX_CMD_NAME     = makeindex
LATEX_MAKEINDEX_CMD    = makeindex
COMPACT_LATEX          = NO
PAPER_TYPE             = a4
EXTRA_PACKAGES         =
LATEX_HEADER           =
LATEX_FOOTER           =
LATEX_EXTRA_STYLESHEET =
LATEX_EXTRA_FILES      =
PDF_HYPERLINKS         = YES
USE_PDFLATEX           = YES
LATEX_BATCHMODE        = NO
LATEX_HIDE_INDICES     = NO
LATEX_SOURCE_CODE      = NO
LATEX_BIB_STYLE        = plain
LATEX_TIMESTAMP        = NO
LATEX_EMOJI_DIRECTORY  =
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the RTF output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_RTF           = NO
RTF_OUTPUT             = rtf
COMPACT_RTF            = NO
RTF_HYPERLINKS         = NO
RTF_STYLESHEET_FILE    =
RTF_EXTENSIONS_FILE    =
RTF_SOURCE_CODE        = NO
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the man page output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_MAN           = NO
MAN_OUTPUT             = man
MAN_EXTENSION          = .3
MAN_SUBDIR             =
MAN_LINKS              = NO
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the XML output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_XML           = NO
XML_OUTPUT             = xml
XML_PROGRAMLISTING     = YES
XML_NS_MEMB_FILE_SCOPE = NO
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the DOCBOOK output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_DOCBOOK       = NO
DOCBOOK_OUTPUT         = docbook
DOCBOOK_PROGRAMLISTING = NO
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options for the AutoGen Definitions output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_AUTOGEN_DEF   = NO
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to Sqlite3 output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the Perl module output
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GENERATE_PERLMOD       = NO
PERLMOD_LATEX          = NO
PERLMOD_PRETTY         = YES
PERLMOD_MAKEVAR_PREFIX =
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the preprocessor
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION        = NO
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = NO
SEARCH_INCLUDES        = YES
INCLUDE_PATH           =
INCLUDE_FILE_PATTERNS  =
PREDEFINED             =
EXPAND_AS_DEFINED      =
SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS   = YES
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to external references
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TAGFILES               =
GENERATE_TAGFILE       =
ALLEXTERNALS           = NO
EXTERNAL_GROUPS        = YES
EXTERNAL_PAGES         = YES
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the dot tool
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CLASS_DIAGRAMS         = YES
DIA_PATH               =
HIDE_UNDOC_RELATIONS   = YES
HAVE_DOT               = NO
DOT_NUM_THREADS        = 0
DOT_FONTNAME           = Helvetica
DOT_FONTSIZE           = 10
DOT_FONTPATH           =
CLASS_GRAPH            = YES
COLLABORATION_GRAPH    = YES
GROUP_GRAPHS           = YES
UML_LOOK               = NO
UML_LIMIT_NUM_FIELDS   = 10
TEMPLATE_RELATIONS     = NO
INCLUDE_GRAPH          = YES
INCLUDED_BY_GRAPH      = YES
CALL_GRAPH             = NO
CALLER_GRAPH           = NO
GRAPHICAL_HIERARCHY    = YES
DIRECTORY_GRAPH        = YES
DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT       = png
INTERACTIVE_SVG        = NO
DOT_PATH               =
DOTFILE_DIRS           =
MSCFILE_DIRS           =
DIAFILE_DIRS           =
PLANTUML_JAR_PATH      =
PLANTUML_CFG_FILE      =
PLANTUML_INCLUDE_PATH  =
DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES    = 50
MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH    = 0
DOT_TRANSPARENT        = NO
DOT_MULTI_TARGETS      = NO
GENERATE_LEGEND        = YES
DOT_CLEANUP            = YES
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen? This is an internal comment, have a look at the \internal` command.

Comment: latest version is a bit vague (and it will be hard to know which version it is, I expect it is, can be obtained with `doxygen -v`:1.8.20 (f246dd2f1c58eea39ea3f50c108019e4d4137bd5)). Is this the complete source file? What is the name of the file? What are the settings in the doxygen configuration file different from the default settings (use `doxygen -x`)? Please don't add this information in a comment but edit it into the, original, question.

Comment: What is the name of the file? Is it the complete file? make a complete file out of it (for testing purposes.

Comment: You still didn't answer the question and remarks in the previous comment: "What is the name of the file? Is it the complete file? make a complete file out of it (for testing purposes)" without this it won't be possible to help you.

Comment: I'm talking about the first code snippet in your question, it looks like php to me.

Comment: Yes, excuse me, indeed I am in php.
Is the code I showed a simple example to illustrate my problem?

In my php code if I want to comment on an "If" which is not in a function, the comment does not appear.

I want to be able to show all the comments I want.

To have a detailed list of the functionality of my pages.

Comment: Doxygen is documenting entities like functions / classes / namespaces / files. There are some limited possibilities to document internal parts, but by head only inside functions, so at the moment I don't think what you want to accomplish is feasible.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me, thank you for your time, do you have an idea, another tool than Doxygen to make my wish come true?

Comment: No idea I only use doxygen